# @Url.Action ViewModel return type returns null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

```
public FileContentResult BtnSearch_Click(SupportSearchViewModel supportSearchViewModel)
        {
            DataTable dt = GetEntries();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
.
.
.
```

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("BtnSearch_Click","Support", new {model = Model })">Suche</a>
```

1. Codeblock: Controller class
2. Codeblock: View class

   it returns a SupportSearchViewModel with null

Im new to this so i tried copy-pasting some answers from SOF, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `@Url.Action` like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("BtnSearch_Click","Support",Model)">Suche</a>
```

Here is a simple demo:

```
public class SupportSearchViewModel {
        public int ViewId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

so that the html will be like:
[image]

And then I test with the following action:

```
public IActionResult BtnSearch_Click(SupportSearchViewModel s)
        {
            return Ok(s);        
        }
```

result:

[image]